# Is this function injective and/or surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is it possible to easily prove if that function is/isn't injective/surjective? $f: x \in Z_{16} \to \overline7 x \in Z_{16}$

My attempt:

It is not injective because $7\overline{x} = \overline{x}$ has for sure a solution $GCD(7,16) = 1$ means that $\overline7$ has a inverse in $Z_{16}$ (and it is $\overline7$). So my counterproof would be:

$f(\overline49)=f(\overline1)=\overline1$ but $\overline1 \neq \overline49$

Is this a valid counterproof?

Comment: $\bar{49}$ DOES equal $\bar{1}$.

Comment: So is it injective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof that 7 has an inverse in $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$ actually shows that the function is injective and surjective; in fact $f$ is its own inverse.

Comment: Why, knowing that 7 has inverse in $Z_{16}$ means that it is both injective and surjective?

Comment: Because then $f(f(x)) = 7(7x) = 49x = x$, so $f = f^{-1}$. Any function that has an inverse is both injective and surjective.

Comment: $f(f(x))=\bar{7}(\bar{7}x)=\bar{1}x=x$

Answer (score 1):

The counterproof isn' t valid because in $\mathbb{Z}_6$ you have the equality $\overline{49}=\overline{1+3\cdot 16}=\overline{1}$.

In fact this function is both an injective and surjective.

It is injective because: $f(\overline{x})=f(\overline{y}) \Rightarrow \overline{7} \overline{x}=\overline{7}\overline{y}\Rightarrow \overline{7}\overline{7}  \overline{x}=\overline{7}\overline{7}\overline{y}\Rightarrow \overline{x}=\overline{y}$

It is subjective because: $f(\overline{7}\overline{x})=\overline{7}\overline{7}\overline{x}=\overline{x}$